# Approximate the log-function using keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

I' m learning neural networks and I want to write a neural network to approximate the log-function. The `x` domain is 1 to 100.
I use `keras` as my tool, but the result is not good. Should I modify the loss function? or add more hidden layers? Finally, how to train my model.
I'm sorry for my poor English.

The code as following:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

x_train = np.linspace(1, 100, num=100)
y_train = np.log2(x_train)

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(units=500, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='normal',
                activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(units=500, kernel_initializer='normal',
                activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))


model.add(Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='normal'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

train_history = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, 
                          validation_split=0.2, epochs=100, batch_size=30,
                          verbose=2)
```

How should I modify my code? Please guide me.

Comment: I think 2 layers of 500 units each might be a bit too big a network for only 100 examples. What happens if you use `np.linspace(1, 10000, num=10000)`? Is it any better?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will try it!

Comment: In addition to having unnecessarily large layers for this small dataset, the dropout slows down the training considerably. To make it work you could (1) reconsider the dropout value and/or (2) increase the number of training epochs and/or (3) increase the learning rate.

Comment: Today I use a 3-layers neural network and the samples are 1 to 10000. The result is better than before. The test data x = 30000 and log2(x) = 14.87, but my model predicts log2(x) = 13.63,  this result seems to be improved.